# Switching off ligatures in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, ligatures

In order to switch off ligatures for a whole document using LuaLaTeX, I put the following lines into the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}   
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
```

However, the output document still shows ligatures. I also tried this command:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}   
\defaultfontfeatures{
  Ligatures={-Required, +NoRequired, -Common, +NoCommon, -Contextual, +NoContextual,
             -TeX, -Rare, -Historic}}
```

but with the same result.

Any ideas why switching off ligatures is not working?

**EDIT:** The anser to my question is hidden in one of the comments on Patrick's answer: It is necessary to explicitly select a font via one of the `fontspec` commands afterwards, in order to have the `Ligatures`setting take effect. For example:

```
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

Comment: LuaTeX is at version 5?

Comment: 5.1 is at least the number my MieKTeX Package Manager mentions for the Lua binaries (miktex-lua51-bin-2.9).

Comment: that would be lua not LuaTeX. Your distribution will come with a version of the lua compiler (as in a compiler of the lua programming language) and this is what you describe. LuaTeX is currently at version 0.70.something

Comment: You should provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Without that (see the comments) we can only guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103238/removing-ligatures-when-using-fontspec

Answer (score 12):

You have three choices to instruct fontspec to suppress ligatures:

The first is to name the default font features that are valid for the next font assignments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
I eat  -- the fluffiest `? ``fish''.
\end{document}
```

You can also add font features to the current font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
I eat  -- the fluffiest `? ``fish''.
\end{document}
```

Or you can instruct fontspec to load a font with the given features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}]{Linux Libertine O}
I eat  -- the fluffiest `? ``fish''.
\end{document}
```

All of these result in:

[image]

Comment: For me that means that I need to set again the default font, whatever that is, because I use LuaLaTeX as a rendering engine for a .NET application. Therefore, I do not know which font is actually the default one on the current system. Is there a command that I can use inside the `\setmainfont{}` command to advise it to use the current mainfont?

Comment: @Dieter you can use `\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}` for that purpose.

Comment: if you use `fontspec` without specifying the fonts, `luatex` should default to `Linux Modern`. Without `fontspec` it should behave like any other latex compiler and use `CM` (unless you specify a `fontencoding`.

Comment: @ArTourter It should be "Latin Modern".

Comment: `\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
\begin{document}
I eat  -- the fluffiest `? ``fish''.
\end{document}`

Comment: I tried the following code, but without success:

`\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
\begin{document}
I eat  -- the fluffiest `? ``fish''.
\end{document}`

It still gives me ligatures (in a serif font).

When I attempt to change the font, LuaLaTeX trys to generate a font names database, but crashes after about half a minute.  I tried to run `mkluatexfontdb` manually, but it again crashed with a fatal error. I am using an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows Vista in an Administrator shell.

Comment: @Dieter if you use the default font, then why do you load fontspec at all? Fontspec does not work with a font that is not loaded by fontspec.

Comment: @Patrick that was not apparent to me. I mistakingly thought by loading the fontspec package it would take over the whole font management including adjusting the default font. -- What would be the best practice for selecting a default font for different systems (Win, Linux, Mac) in the same source file?

Comment: @Dieter A default font is, well, a default font. No need to select anything.

Comment: @Patrick I ment: If Fontspec does not work with a font that is not loaded by fontspec, I need somehow to specify the default font again with a Fontspec command, correct? What is the best way to do this platform neutral?

Comment: @Dieter `\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}]{Latin Modern Roman}` should do the trick. If not, please ask a separate question here on this site. This way more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to suppress the "bad" ligatures, you can go for the [selnolig](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures) package. Be aware that one has to use the [fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontspec) package then.

English:

```
\usepackage[english]{selnolig}
```

German:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{selnolig}
```

More information: [New package, selnolig, that automates suppression of typographic ligatures](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures)

Discussion regarding fontspec and lualatex: [Can we stop recommending fontspec as first choice in case lualatex is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338781/9075)