# Locally disabling en and em dash ligatures

Tags: pdftex, punctuation, ligatures

A programming tool that I use (`coqdoc`) generates LaTeX documentation from my source code. Parts of the manual include pretty-printed code listings and math proofs.

These listings and proofs are rather math-heavy, and thus are not wrapped in `verbatim` or `lstlistings`. When successions of dashes are found (`--` or `---`) in code or proofs, they are dumped literally in the LaTeX output, and thus get converted to `–` and `—` as the document is typeset by `pdflatex`. Code and proof listings are wrapped in a particular environment, which I can renew.

**What can I add to my preamble to disable en and em dash ligatures in that specific environment?**

Ideally, I would like something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewenvironment{coqdoccode}{MAGIC HERE}{}

\begin{document}
This should be an an and an em dash: -- ---
\begin{coqdoccode}
  This should be two and three small dashes: -- ---
  This should still be ligatures: ff fi
\end{coqdoccode}
\end{document}
```

`microtype` only seems to be able to disable ligatures at the entire document level.

Comment: Is LuaLaTeX an option? [Switching off ligatures in LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54459/2693)

Comment: Unfortunately no; the output of the tool is heavily reliant on pdflatex.

Comment: The `verbatim` environment use `\@noligs` to stop `--` ligatures, and the tt font has no ff ligatures, is monospace acceptable for this use?

Answer (score 8):

Activate the hyphen in the `coqdoccode` environment, defining it as a hyphen followed by a zero kern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\activatehyphen}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\char`\-\kern0pt }%
  \catcode`\-=\active
}

\newenvironment{coqdoccode}
  {\flushleft\activatehyphen\ttfamily}
  {\endflushleft}

\begin{document}
This should be an an and an em dash: -- ---
\begin{coqdoccode}
  This should be two and three small dashes: -- --- \\
  This should still be ligatures: ff fi \\
\end{coqdoccode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added `\ttfamily` just for clarity, but it's not necessary.

This is the result without `\ttfamily` in the definition

[image]

Comment: I don't see ligatures for `ff` and `fi` in the last output...

Comment: @Bakuriu That's because I used `\ttfamily`.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Could you explain how this works? I understand that it makes `-` active, but I'm not sure what the `\lowercase` and `\lccode` parts do.

Comment: @Clément See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick