# LuaLaTeX: Unable to switch off ligatures in smallcaps

Tags: luatex, fontspec, small-caps

I am aware of a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54459/switching-off-ligatures-in-lualatex), but that answer doesn't seem to help.

I am unable to switch off ligatures when using smallcaps. The following MWE is using Minion, but I tried with many similar fonts: Dante, Merlo, Caslon, etc.

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}

\newfontfamily\MinionSmallCaps
[Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual},
Letters={UppercaseSmallCaps,SmallCaps},
LetterSpace=80,WordSpace=3]
{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoRequired, NoCommon, NoContextual}}
\MinionSmallCaps Test is here [Minion]
\end{document}
```

Environment on my machine:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
fontspec-luatex.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e
fontspec-patches.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e    
luaotfload.sty    2015/12/09 v2.6
```

Results:

[image]

I am able to have the desired result, using the same text and same font, using InDesign:

[image]

InDesign settings:

[image]

How can one completely switch off ligatures while using smallcaps with LuaLaTeX?

---

**Edit 1**

Writing "testate" and using "Minionpro", as suggested by @ulrike-fischer throws an error:

```
luaotfload-letterspace.lua:445: You cannot set field prev.next in a node of type glyph
```

The results is this one:

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

Using a similar free font, Cardo, with

```
\CardoSmallCaps Testate is here [Cardo]
```

The result is this one:

[image]

The ligatures are off, although the Letters={UppercaseSmallCaps,SmallCaps} directive seems not to be respected perfectly.

---

**Edit 3**

As @egreg said,

> It really seems a bug in `luaotfload`, if not in LuaTeX.

I am monitoring luaotfload's tracker, especially [this issue](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/309) which seems related. I shall report back as soon as I have news.

Comment: Just to add a detail: I am aware of a recent bug in luaotfload (https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases/tag/v2.6-fix-1), so I have been using Luaotfload v2.6-fix-2, although the logs still say v2.6.

Comment: It doesn't look like a ligature problem, more as if wordspace would not work at the end of words. What happens if you write "testate" and "Minionpro"? (I don't have the font, so I can't test.)

Comment: Thanks, I have added results with your suggestion in the question. luaotfload throws an error, but it was not doing it before. I could use a different font, if you prefer?

Comment: A font available in a texsystem or for free would be better.

Comment: I have added a second edit, trying with Cardo. Interestingly, the ligatures are now off. Is that a problem with the chosen font, then? Why the same OpenType font would work with InDesign?

Comment: It seems there are bugs with the latest version of luaotfload. See for example: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/309

Comment: It really seems a bug in `luaotfload`, if not in LuaTeX.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. I have quoted your comment to question. I shall report back.

Comment: @gsl If I write `estate` with Linux Libertine as font, I get no letter spacing in `TAT`, but an error with Minion Pro. So there's some problem when letters are kerned.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I saw somebody already pointed to this question from that ticket. I hope the maintainers will take care of this soon. Or else I will need to use older package, sometimes it is not easy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug seems to be solved with `luaotfload` version 2.6-fix-4, released 2015-12-24.

Here's the output of your very example:

[image]

The error with `Testate` does not show any more.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg it was indeed a bug. See https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases/tag/v2.6-fix-3 and https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases/tag/v2.6-fix-4 Also, do not forget to do `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` (PS: @egreg, you are indefatigable! "Buon Anno" to the TeX champion)