# Unable to supress ligatures in headings which are set in Caps

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, selnolig

I am aware that similar questions have been asked a few times. However, none of the answers solved my problem. [This Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284705/133359) says that it is a bug in `luaotfload`. But I'm already using a newer version (2.80001).

I'm trying to supress ligatures via [selnolig package](https://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig?lang=de). It works great, but not for text that was set in capitals. Using [microtypes](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype?lang=de) `\DisableLigatures` or [selnolig package](https://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig?lang=de) `\breaklig` also has no effect. See MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    DIV=9,
    fontsize=14pt,
    parskip=half-
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[%
    Ligatures=Common,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps},
]

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{160}
\usepackage[ngerman]{selnolig}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\scshape\mdseries\Large}
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\mdseries\Large}
]{subsection}

\begin{document}
% Heading set in caps => ligature still present
\section{Berufliche Praxis}
Berufliche Praxis\par
ff fl fi

% Using \breaklig command => ligature still present
\section{Beruf\breaklig liche Praxis}

% Disabling selnolig => works as expected
\selnoligoff
\section{Berufliche Praxis}
\selnoligon

% No caps => works as expected
\subsection{Berufliche Praxis}

\end{document}
```

[image: (very high tracking to make it clearer)]

So the [selnolig package](https://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig?lang=de) takes care that ligatures in *Berufliche* gets suppressed. This is correct. But it does not work for headings with small caps. Adding `\selnoligoff` right before the `\section` seems to be the only way to supress ligatures in headings with small caps? Or have I missed a setting? I'm wondering which package is responsible for this bug.

Comment: `\section{Beruf\kern0ptliche Praxis}`

Comment: Okay, `\kern0pt` works. Although this is rather inconvenient because it must be applied separately to each and every occurrence of all words that contain unwanted ligatures. The shortcut `"|`(provided by babel) does not work.

Comment: Is `\kern0pt` any more inconvenient that the attempted `\breaklig`?

Comment: No by any means. I was just looking for a more global approach.

Comment: Okay, I think that's coming over wrong. I did not want to blame any package for this problem. I apologize, that was not really my intention. I am glad that there is a package that allows such accurate settings for ligatures. It really is a great help, especially for very long texts, where a manual check is not possible. To be honest, I only noticed it after adjusting the tracking using microtype. Since microtype with lualatex does not support interword spacing (which should also be adjusted when changing the tracking) I guess I have to cut corners anyway.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that ligatures in letterspaced settings should always be turned off. Ulrikes approach (using `SmallCapsFeatures={Ligatures=CommonOff}`) actually was my first approach. However, it has no effect in headings.

Comment: I added an issue here https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/53.

Comment: The next luaotfload version will resolve the problem (for the automatic case, not for `\breaklig` which inserts a 0pt space).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an automated approach that reconditions the arguments of `\section` to look for specified ligatures, such as `fl` and to replace them with, for example, `f\kern0ptl`.

In the MWE, look for the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` for the approach.

As an aside, I actually used the same method to also increase the default kern of the space character in small-caps section titles.

Shown for ligatures `fl` and `ff`.  Can easily add more as needed.

EDITED to handle star sections/toc.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    DIV=9,
    fontsize=14pt,
    parskip=half-
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[%
    Ligatures=Common,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps},
]

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{160}
\usepackage[ngerman]{selnolig}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\scshape\mdseries\Large}
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\mdseries\Large}
]{subsection}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{listofitems}
\expandafter\def\csname{fl}lig\endcsname{f\kern0ptl}% fl
\expandafter\def\csname{ff}lig\endcsname{f\kern0ptf}% ff
\expandafter\def\csname{ }lig\endcsname{\hspace{11pt}}% INCREASE SPACE KERN
\setsepchar{fl||ff|| }% CONCATENATE THE DESIRED LIGATURES WITH || "OR"
\let\svsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\starsection}{\nostarsection}}
\newcommand\starsection[1]{%
  \tmptitle{#1}%
  \svsection*{\tmp}%
}
\newcommand\nostarsection[2][\relax]{%
  \tmptitle{#2}%
  \if\relax#1\relax\svsection[#2]{\tmp}\else%
    \svsection[#1]{\tmp}%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\tmptitle[1]{%
  \readlist\myligs{#1}%
  \def\tmp{}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\myligs{%
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\x}%
      \ifnum\xcnt<\listlen\myligs[]\relax
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\g@addto@macro
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \csname{\myligssep[\xcnt]}lig\endcsname}%
      \fi
    }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\hrulefill
\section[blah Berufliche]{Berufliche Praxis}

\section{Hoffähige Praxis}

\subsection{Berufliche Praxis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, I shouldn't mention the crazy stuff you can do with this approach.  But I will.  Adding these lines (and the `xcolor` package):

```
\expandafter\def\csname{e}lig\endcsname{\kern3pt\textcolor{red}{e}\kern1pt}
\setsepchar{fl||ff|| ||e}% CONCATENATE THE DESIRED LIGATURES WITH || "OR"
```

produces this result:

[image]

Comment: @Mico Thanks.  Done.  Plus support for increased space kerns.

Comment: This looks like a really sophisticated hack. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 8):

With a current luaotfload (version 2.96) you can disable the ligatures in the SmallCapsFeatures:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    DIV=9,
    fontsize=14pt,
    parskip=half-
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[%
    Ligatures=Common,
    SmallCapsFeatures=
      {Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps,
       Ligatures=CommonOff}, %disable ligatures
]

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{160}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\scshape\mdseries\Large}
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    font={\mdseries\Large}
]{subsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Berufliche Praxis}
Berufliche Praxis\par
ff fl fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still get the FL ligature though when I load `selnolig`. As in the OP `selnolig` has to be turned off explicitly to get rid of the ligature.

Comment: @moewe Ah yes, selnolig interferes.

Comment: @moewe and \selnoligoff works by paragraph and doesn't respect tex grouping, so you can add it simply to the font commands ;-(.

Comment: I guess you meant “so you *can't* add…”? So `selnolig` is the one to “blame”? Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico could comment on that?

Comment: Yes I meant "can't", and selnolig is not really to blame, but you need a more complicated setup to reset the setting after the section.